# What are the most popular sun-synchronous orbits?

Tags: sun-synchronous

There are different kinds of sun-synchronous orbits (SSO) that differ in their right ascension of the ascending node and are usually named after the local solar time at the ascending node (LTAN), e.g. 9h LTAN.
I am trying to find information or statistics about how the SSO satellites (I am mainly interested in active satellites) are distributed in relation to LTAN, but I couldn't find anything so far. I am looking forward to any kind of advice, links and help!

Comment: Welcome to Space Stack Exchange.  I was wondering what you mean by "in relation to LTAN for days".  If you go to https://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements you can find lists of satellites with their orbit parameters, from which you can roughly estimate LTAN.

Comment: Sorry, "for days" was a typo. It's supposed to be only "in relation to LTAN". I will definitely check out Celestrak. Thanks for the advice!